# Rims stuck on car with plastic hub centric rings

Tags: ford, wheels, mustang

I think I forced my new rims with plastic hub centric rings and now they are stuck, I can't remove the rims off the car.

I have a mustang 07

Comment: My alloys have been known to freeze on as well, a large soft-faced mallet and a VERY good support, then you have to hit it - the tyre preferably and should come off.

Comment: I'll try that, but it is really stuck in there, I tried kicking the tire and it didn't even moved. I was thinking on applying heat, do you think if I do that i could damage the rims or something else?

Comment: Squirt some WD-40 on the center hubs and let soak a few hours, then try removal again.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with this issue I would suggest that you support the car on solid good quality axle stands - or take it to a garage who can put it on a ramp.

Then you need to use a large soft-faced mallet and hit them from the inside ie underneath of the car to knock them off. It is best to hit the tyre not the rim...

I suggest that you do not apply heat as you will melt / deform the plastic.

Kicking them is about as good as good as hitting them with a feather - at least kicking mine did not work, but that was alloys corroded onto the hub. Kicking them may work if you kick them off ie away from the vehicle.